# Assumptions in sympy arbitrary functions

Tags: python, sympy

With SymPy we can set assumptions on variables:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
x, re(x), im(x)
```

the result is :

```
(x,x,0)
```

as expected. But if we try to do the same for a function:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
f = Function('f', real=True)(x)

f, re(f), im(f)
```

the result is :

```
(f(x),re(f(x)),im(f(x)))
```

but I expected something as

```
(f(x),f(x),0)
```

The question is then: Is there a way to make python assume the range of the function to be real, i.e.

In this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298497/sympy-arbitrary-function-range) it is partially answered, but if the we take the derivative we get again the same problem:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
class f(Function):
    is_positive = True
df = f(x).diff(x)


df, re(df), im(df)
```

with result:

```
(f(x).diff(x),re(f(x).diff(x)),im(f(x).diff(x)))
```

wanting it to be like

```
(f(x).diff(x),f(x).diff(x),0)
```

is there a way?

Comment: I think you might have to subclass `Function` and define an `_eval_is_real` method. The docs are pretty lacking, but they do happen to have an example of defining a function whose value is real when its argument is real, and that's what the example does.

Comment: I would consider this to be a bug. Derivative should be smart enough to know that the derivative of a real function is real.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11868